# Getting the type of report Programmatically

Tags: apex, community, joined-reports

I want to identify the type of the report pro-grammatically.

I am using

```
Reports.ReportDescribeResult describe = Reports.ReportManager.describeReport(objReport.Id);
```

But it fails for Joined reports.Is there any other method to identify report type for joined reports?

Comment: I am using this to get the records from Reports. 
Reports.ReportMetadata reportMd = describe.getReportMetadata();
  List<Reports.ReportFilter> filter = reportMd.getReportFilters();
          // Run a report
                Reports.ReportResults reportResults = Reports.ReportManager.runReport(strSelectedReport,true);
                String factMapKey; 
                 Reports.ReportFactWithDetails factDetails = (Reports.ReportFactWithDetails)reportResults.getFactMap().get(factMapKey); But this fails for for joined reports.

Comment: This feature is not supported for joined report : http://peterknolle.com/apex-analytics-api-and-report-chart-component/  . Is there any other way to get records from joined reports.

Answer (score 0):

You can query for it.

```
SELECT Format FROM Report WHERE Id = :objReport.Id
```

The `Format` picklist has four values: 'Joined', 'Matrix', 'Summary', 'Tabular' (default).